What does てはいそう mean?
Context: adventurer is shocked about rare skill of newcomer. These two sentences are spoken by the same person one after another.

スキルは極一部の人間だけ使える秘宝でしか分からないから我々は感覚で理解するしかない
スキルな持ってますと言われてはいそうですかとはいかない

My guessed translation (because I don't fully grasp first sentence either) for these would be:

Only few people know abouts skills, so we can only intuitively use them. (I guessed he means that there are no guides about how to use skills)
Even if you say you have skill, (?) I can't believe you? (my assumption is that はいそう is:


は - for just accent first part
い - part of いる
そう - ending for "it seems that" which removed る part (but that doesn't make sence to use this ending with 言われて)

So the question is: what is actually going on in these sentences?

～と言われて「はい、そうですか」とはいかない。
I can't just accept it, just because you say you have a "skill" (without an explanation/proof/etc).
